# how to change the cloud archive mirror in juju?

Tags: juju, openstack

Installing openstack charms is taking forever because of the pipeline to canonical.com:

```
... http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/kilo/main python-swiftclient all 1:2.3.1-0ubuntu1~cloud0 [41.0 kB]
```

Is there a way to change the mirror in juju for all of the nodes?

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you may be able to get around this issue by configuring a [proxy for Juju](http://www.jujucharms.com/docs/stable/juju-misc#configure-proxy-access)

See in particular the heading on apt-proxy. There is more general information on setting specific options in [the general configuration page of the docs](https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/models-config)